# Can I access Lotus Notes' database?

Tags: database, lotus-notes

This is my first time working with Lotus notes so I only know how to use it. I am also a developer so I know a bit about databases. Currently I receive requests for adding users to AD accounts or disabling users from AD or even modifying their attributes in AD. These requests come to me through Lotus Notes. I was wondering that Lotus Notes has to have some sort of database so **could I possible get access to these ESM requests through their databse? So what I am saying is, can I access these ESM requests directly through database and not Lotus Notes?**

EDIT: I have worked wiht PHP/mySQL before so my goal here is to treat Lotus Note's database like an SQL database so I can query it through some script to generate csv versions of the requests. Because of my lack of experience with Lotus Notes or its database I don't know whether I can access or query the Lotus notes database like I do wiht PHP/mySQL.

Comment: This is a very general question.  Yes, Lotus Notes has "some sort of database".  It's not a relational database, but there is a way to access it via SQL, although there are other ways that are better for the majority of use cases.  You've not told us how you get these "ESM requests".  (You haven't even told us what an "ESM request" is! That's not a term that Notes programmers deal with.)  Do you receive them in Lotus Notes mail messages?  Do you open a special application in your Lotus Notes client?

Comment: Not to offend you, but why would you want to convert it to CSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find information about the NotesSQL driver [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/documentation/notessql/).  It may or may not be all that you need for this project -- but given the lack of detail in your question (see my comment above), it's hard to say.

If you want to learn a bit more about Lotus Notes development, so you at least know the necessary basic concepts before you try to dive into this project, you might want to start by installing Domino Designer and going through some of the basic help info that you find there.  There are also a number of good books that cover it, and there's also some free introductory online [courseware](http://www.tlcc.com/admin/tlccsite.nsf/pages/free+course) (third party) for first-time Notes developers.  An older book -- geared toward Java programming for Lotus Notes, and dated on a lot of details -- but still with a lot of very good basic concept information, was posted online by the author [here](http://www.bobzblog.com/tuxedoguy.nsf/dx/programming-domino-with-java-final-flush).

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this. I haven't used Lotus notes before so this is my first time. I get the ESM in some sort of ticket format that I mark complete once the ticket is resolved. I will give the driver a try. This driver from IBM isn't free so I will try to find a freeware instead.

Comment: Are you opening the ticket in a browser, in Lotus Notes itself or in an email?

Comment: The ticket appears to be a custom form in some database.  What database is it in?  Is it in the user's mail database?  Or is it in some other database?  And what are the field names and types of the items on the form?  If you don't know the answers to these questions, then you need to talk to the sponsor of your project and/or the developer of the ticketing system.  Just as you couldn't  possibly do this for a SQL database without knowing the schema, you can't do this for a Notes database either without knowing this basic information.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you say that the NotesSQL driver isn't free.  Perhaps it's changed, but I don't ever remember IBM charging for it.